# Output needs to be in text(not object)

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I print outputs like this in my code, but I was told that my outputs needs to be in text(not object). Can somebody explain to me what it means and whats wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
Write-Output "ALL INSTALLED WINDOWS FEATURES:" 
Write-Verbose -Message "Searching installed features..." -Verbose
$obj=Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Installed} | Select-Object Name, InstallState | Format-Table -AutoSize
Write-Output $obj

Write-Output "OPERATING SYSTEM INFO:"
Write-Verbose -Message "Searching operating system info..." -Verbose
$opInfo=Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Version, Caption, InstallDate, LastBootUpTime, TotalVirtualMemorySize , SystemDirectory | FL
Write-Output $opInfo
```

Comment: You're currently outputting objects (the right way). Someone is asking you to output text. What is your question?

Comment: Ask more details from whoever told you that text is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing technically wrong with your code but personally I would change `Write-Output "OPERATING SYSTEM INFO:"` to a `Write-Verbose`, having that header in the output will make working with the results of your function in other parts of the code.  However returning the object `opInfo` rather than a collection of strings is absolutely correct and the only reason someone would be telling you not to is if the code they intend what you are creating to interact with is either written incorrectly or written in an older scripting language like VBS, or if they are just not aware the preference for objects in Powershell development.